# How can I move back and forth between two forms without loosing entered data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialogresult

i have two forms which i want to move back and forth with without loosing the data that i have entered on both form, when i go back to form1 from form2 the data remains in form1, but when i go to form2 in which i have entered data before, the data are all gone, is there a solution to this?

first form:

```
public userform1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void jThinButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userform2 form2 = new userform2();
    form2.Show();

    this.Hide();
    form2.Hide();
    form2.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
```

second form:

```
private void jThinButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

going back to form2 from form1 works fine, but the problem is I loose the data I have entered in form2 when I click next in form1, I want to keep the entered data in form 2, is it possible?

Comment: Declare your other form as a member of your first form class (not inside your event handler), so that it stays in scope while your first form is still open.

Comment: You are creating a ***new*** form2 every time then hiding it - you arent loosing anything, just not using the same form.  Declare the form outside the method

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Im sorry, do you have the code for that?

Comment: Just declare UserForm2 in UserForm1's class scope.  If you don't know what that means, well..

Comment: Consider using Tab controls (or similar) so neither you nor the user have to navigate *four* forms to do something relatively simple.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate your userform2 instance in a readonly property which creates a new one if it's not created already

```
private userform2 _form2;
private userform2 form2
{
    get
    {
        if (_form2 == null)
            _form2 = new userform2();
        return _form2;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
this.Hide();
form2.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

now whenever you access `form2` its the same instance of userform2.

Or simply if you want to use the field only, but the instance is created when userform1 is constructed.

```
private userform2 form2 = new userform2();
```

Comment: At least get rid of the un-necessary `form2.Show()` and `form2.Hide()` calls.  All you need is `form2.ShowDialog()`...  =)

Comment: @Idle_Mind sure